# Excluding unwanted results of findAll using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Using BeautifulSoup, I am aiming to scrape the text associated with this HTML hook:

```html
<p class="review_comment">
```

So, using the simple code as follows,

```
content = page.read()  
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)  
results = soup.find_all("p", "review_comment")
```

I am happily parsing the text that is living here:

```html
<p class="review_comment">
    This place is terrible!</p>
```

The bad news is that every 30 or so times the `soup.find_all` gets a match, it also matches and grabs something that I really don't want, which is a user's old review that they've since updated:

```html
<p class="review_comment">
    It's 1999, and I will always love this place…  
<a href="#" class="show-archived">Read more &raquo;</a></p>
```

In my attempts to exclude these old duplicate reviews, I have tried a hodgepodge of ideas.

- I've been trying to alter the arguments in my `soup.find_all()` call
  to specifically exclude any text that comes *before* the `<a href="#"
  class="show-archived">Read more &raquo;</a>`
- I've drowned in Regular Expressions-type matching limbo with no success.
- I can't seem to take advantage of the `class="show-archived"` attribute.

Any ideas would be gratefully appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the "bad news match" is it just the inner A tag and contents that you don't want or do you want to reject the whole P?

Comment: Yes the "bad news match" is an old review and I want to reject the whole thing.  One major reason for this is because I've also scraped the "# of stars" information, but suddenly I have more reviews than stars.

Comment: Are you aware of the special way to spell [class_](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) in soup.find()?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is this what you are seeking?

```
for p in soup.find_all("p", "review_comment"):
    if p.find(class_='show-archived'):
        continue
    # p is now a wanted p
```

Comment: This is the strategy I need to use, yes.  It is a simple matter of using the correct loop.  Thank you for your help @msw!