# how to use beautiful soup to get all text "except" a specific class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use `soup.get_text` to get some text out of a webpage, but I want to exclude a specific class.

I tried to use `a = soup.find_all(class_ = "something")` and `b=[i.get_text() for i in a]`, but that allows me to choose one class, and doesn't allow me to exclude one specific class.

I also tried:
`a = soup.select('span:not([class_ ="something"])') b = [i.get_text() for i in a]`
first, the output wasn't really text only. but most important; it gave me all classes including "something" that I wanted to exclude.

Is there some other way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

example:

```
link = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74620106/how-to-use-beautiful-soup-to-get-all-text-except-a-specific-class"
f = urlopen(link)

soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
a = soup.find_all(class_ = "mt24 mb12")
b = [i.get_text() for i in a]

text = soup.select('div:not([class_ ="mt24 mb12"])')
text1 = [i.get_text() for i in text]
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample HTML code and what elements do you want to extract from that HTML code?

Comment: My actual saple is in hebrew, so maybe it's not that readable. So I'll put this question as exaple.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all classes but one for example, you can loop through all element and choose the ones you keep:

```
for p in soup.find_all("p", "review_comment"):
    if p.find(class_="something-archived"):
        continue
    # p is now a wanted p
```

source: [Excluding unwanted results of findAll using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351541/excluding-unwanted-results-of-findall-using-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0):

You can extract them from the soup object, then call the get_text method [(adapted from @fábio-diniz)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5598678/4466012):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<span>Unwanted span 1</span>Keep this!<span>Unwanted span 2</span>', 'html.parser')
for s in soup.select('span'):
    s.extract()
print(soup.get_text())
Keep this!
```